# Did you spend it with her?

Tags: idiomatic-language, grammaticality-in-context

*How did your daughter's birthday go? **Did you spend it with her?***

I know you'd normally be talking about who you'd be spending your own birthday with, but do you think the question in the above context would be acceptable as well?

Comment: It should be grammatically correct I think

Comment: "I know you'd normally be talking about who you'd be spending your own birthday with"  I don't understand this comment.  You can talk about anybody's birthday.  I don't see it as being any more normal to talk about "your own birthday" as talking about "your daughter's birthday".

Answer (score 2):

You can speak of spending any period of time in a certain way; the fact that it's someone's birthday makes no difference.

> I spent an hour tidying the kitchen.
>
> I'm spending Christmas with my parents.
>
> She will spend a year studying overseas.